# Verificar se Sim Card está instalado

Tags: android

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se é possível verificar se o sim card no aparelho está instalado no Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma consulta rápida na documentação revela a função [`TelephonyManager.getSimState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState()). Pode ser usada assim:

```
final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (telephony.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY) {
    // ...
}
```

O valor retornado é um dos seguintes:

```
SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN // Em transição entre dois estados
SIM_STATE_ABSENT
SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED
SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED
SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED
SIM_STATE_READY
```

Você pode ainda definir um callback para notificar que a situação do SIM mudar:

```
telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
        // Verifique aqui a situação do SIM
    }
});
```

Comment: Vale acresecentar que alguns estados do TelephonyManager também são aplicados com o SIM Card inserido no dispositivo (`SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED` e outros), acho que apenas o `SIM_STATE_ABSENT` e o `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` podem significar que o SIM Card não está presente. E ainda vale lembrar que podem haver dispositivos com 2 Slot's, e esse método só retorna o estado do primeiro Slot.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.